# Tool for protocol or interface description

Tags: uml, protocols, specifications, enterprise-architect

We have to develop a protocol as a interface description between different systems in different companies. The implementations will be made in different languages (not known) by the developers in each company.

However, we want to develop the protocol on a textual description base together. I will have the base copy of the current version and want to send it out to all for comments.

**What is a good tool to do so?**

At the moment we are using MS Word what leads to several problems:

- We need a lot of time for text formatting things.
- Its not possible to reference to a datatype in the methods description.
- The wording differs from chapter to chapter (different authors) and is hard to align.

Perfect would be:

- A tool with a glossary and auto-completion.
- References to other items (methods, data types, ...) with active links.
- Automatic generation of a human-readable (PDF-) document.

**Do you know such a tool?**

PS: I did not get Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect doing the job. Maybe also hints for this one?

Comment: I suggest pure html files.

Comment: @user2511414: how does this meet my requirements?

Comment: I always use `xhtml` for documenting, and about the formatting, you would use a tool(maybe eclipse), it contains spell check and bunch of cool stuff. and about the modelling I suggest `UMLet`, it's free and cool.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very big question, since there are many possible aspects you may (should) wish to document in a protocol specification. The two most important ones would be data structures and message sequences, then there's error management, authentication, timing, etc etc.

UML can certainly be used to describe these things, and Enterprise Architect is eminently able to generate versatile documentation from a model - it will definitely help with your reference issues. But first you will have to determine quite strictly how each aspect of the protocol is to be modelled, and from that you will need to construct the necessary EA configuration / adaptation.

In order to get good quality documents out of EA, I recommend generating the documents from an Add-In using the Object Model's DocumentGenerator class as this gives you more flexibility than the traditional RTF generator - for one thing, you can access Word's API in addition to EA's and thus do far more with the document than is possible using EA's API alone.

Without knowing the size or complexity of your protocol, I'd say this would require at the very least a few weeks' work for someone who is experienced in writing EA adaptations. But if the scope of your project is such that there are several companies involved, it is likely to be worth the investment.